# What is the difference between "dodge" and "shun"?

Tags: phrases

For example:

> He keeps *shunning* (or *dodging*) me, because he owes me some money.

Which one is correct? If both, which one is more appropriate?

The dictionary I checked wasn't too helpful:

> Shun:  avoid somebody/something
>
> Dodge: to avoid doing something, especially in a dishonest way

Comment: Do me a favor and copy/paste the definitions of these two words into your question, from your favorite dictionary (make sure to name the specific dictionary you used), then elaborate on any questions you have remaining.

Comment: I think @Dan means, please do _us_ a favor... These questions can be tedious to answer when you ask, "What is the difference between X and Y?" because the first step in answering these questions is looking them up in the dictionary – something that you should be doing, not the people who are answering. Please read [this meta question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439), [this meta answer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please/465#465), and then see [this ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63039) for a great example.

Comment: The part about "dodge" suggesting dishonesty is not consistent. One can speak about "dodging a bullet", which means avoiding a catastrophic outcome and has no disapproving overtone, while "dodging a question" does indeed suggest dishonesty.

Answer (score 3):

I see enough ambiguity in the definitions to warrant the question.

To *dodge* someone|something is to avoid them|it because you don't want them|it to see you or accost you.

**We might dodge an organized crime "hit man", or dodge a question.**

To *shun* someone|something is to avoid them|it because you have chosen to ignore or "turn your back on" them|it.

The difference lies in the motive and also in the manner. Dodging is done on an ad hoc basis, when the need arises. Shunning is planned and deliberate and ongoing.

**We might shun an acquaintance who committed a felony, or shun casinos.**

In Pennsylvania where I live (and elsewhere) the Amish, a religious community (who are portrayed in the film *Witness* by Australian director Peter Weir) will *shun* a member of their community who has committed in their estimation a very serious sin; they treat the person as though he or she did not exist.

Comment: I also think shunning has a connotation of "consistently". If I shunned you yesterday, I'll shun you today, and probably tomorrow. If I dodged my landlord on Thursday, I might not dodge him on Friday after I've been paid and have the money for the rent.

Comment: I'd add that 'dodge' implies I am actively moving out of your 'line of sight' to avoid being noticed, whilst 'shun' more implies that I see you, yet I blank your presence as though you didn't exist.

Comment: I agree with you both. "Consistently" and "as though you didn't exist" are definitely part and parcel of shunning.

Comment: So, in my sentence about owing money, which one is more appropriate, "keep dodging me" or "keep shunning me"?

Comment: @Jokaec: What do you think the more appropriate one is?  Are you more like a hit man to him, or more like a sinner?  :)

Comment: Your mention of the Amish made clear to me that there is a connotation of judgment with shun. I would use shun for things and people I disapprove of, while I would use dodge when I'm avoiding a meeting that might be unpleasant or inconvenient.